# INNER JOIN com 3 tabelas sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho 3 tabelas no banco de dados:

**tbl_cupom_gerado:**

```
id_cupom  |    nome
 ------        -----
   40          João 
   60          Maria
```

**tbl_cupom:**

```
  id      |    desconto        |   id_estabelecimento
 ----          --------               -------
  40         50% de desconto             1
  60         20% de desconto             2
```

**tbl_estabelecimento:**

```
  id      |    nome
  ---         ------
   1         Agência X
   2         Agência Y
```

Gostaria de integrar as tabelas de forma a relacionar o id_cupom da tbl_cupom_gerado com o desconto de tbl_cupom e o nome de tbl_estabelecimento, com o objetivo de dar SELECT no nome, desconto e nome do estabelecimento.
Elaborei um código com INNER JOINs, porém não tem êxito. O que posso corrigir?

```
SELECT nome, tbl_cupom.desconto, tbl_estabelecimento.nome
       FROM tbl_cupom_gerado, tbl_cupom 
       INNER JOIN tbl_cupom ON tbl_cupom.id = tbl_cupom_gerado.id_cupom
       INNER JOIN tbl_estabelecimento ON tbl_estabelecimento.id = tbl_cupom.id_estabelecimento
```

Comment: Mas está dando algum erro? Ou simplesmente não retorna nenhum dado? A única coisa "errada" é que você não está especificando de qual tabela você quer o primeiro "nome". Uma dica, crie alias para as tabelas por exemplo: From tbl_cupom as c.

Comment: Não estava retornando nenhum dado, mas consegui corrigir. Especifiquei os dados das tabelas como você comentou, e removi o tbl_cupom do FROM deixando só o tbl_cupom_gerado. Valeu pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Experimente remover a segunda tabela no seu "FROM". Deixe apenas "FROM tbl_cupom_gerado" e tente executar o código.

Comment: Removi e deu certo! Também especifiquei os dados do tbl_cupom_gerado no SELECT

Comment: Massa! Que bom que deu certo. Abraço!